# Can I hatch this region in any way?

Tags: graphics

Can I hatch this region in any way?

```
Graphics[{
Circle[{0,0},10,{ArcCos[5/10],ArcCos[5Sqrt[3]/10]}],
Line[{{5Sqrt[3],5},{5Sqrt[3],-5}}],
Circle[{0,0},10,{-ArcCos[5/10],-ArcCos[5Sqrt[3]/10]}],
Line[{{5,-5Sqrt[3]},{5,5Sqrt[3]}}]
},
Axes->True,
AxesOrigin->{0,0}
]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I want to define a region of a circle, because I want to determine the area of this region...

[image]

Comment: For what purpose?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:** Version 12.1 comes with new directives [`PatternFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html) and [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) that can be use as the option setting for `PlotStyle`:

```
RegionPlot[reg, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> PatternFilling["Diamond", ImageScaled[.025]], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
  Prolog -> {Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 10]},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[reg, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, HatchFilling["Diagonal", 3, 5]], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 Prolog -> {Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 10]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 100 && 5 <= x <= 5 Sqrt[3], {x, y}];
N[Area[reg]]
```

> 52.3599

```
Show[Graphics[{Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 10]}, Axes -> True], 
 RegionPlot[reg, MeshFunctions -> {# + #2 &, # - #2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {50, 50}, MeshShading -> None, PlotStyle -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 100 && 5 <= x <= 5 Sqrt[3],{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# + #2 &, # - #2 &}, Mesh -> {50, 50}, 
 MeshShading -> None, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Red, 
 PlotPoints -> 90, Axes -> True, Epilog -> {Gray, Scale[Circle[], 10]}, 
 Frame -> False]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 5):

```
poly = MeshPrimitives[
    BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
     RegionIntersection[
      Disk[],
      HalfPlane[{{5/10, 0}, {5/10, 1}}, {1, 0}],
      HalfPlane[{{5 Sqrt[3]/10, 0}, {5 Sqrt[3]/10, 1}}, {-1, 0}]
      ],
     MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.001}
     ],
    2
    ][[1]];
Area[poly]
```

> 0.523599

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Gray, EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], poly}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
   Graphics[{Red, Opacity@0.7, Disk[{0, 0}, 10], Opacity@1, Blue, Thick, 
      Circle[{0, 0}, 10, {π/6, π/3}], 
      Circle[{0, 0}, 10, {-(π/6), -(π/3)}], Green, Opacity@0.6, 
      Rectangle[{10 Cos[π/3], -10 Sin[π/3]}, {10 Cos[π/6], 
        10 Sin[π/3]}]}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Therefore we can use the following.

```
reg1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 10];
reg2 = Rectangle[{10 Cos[π/3], -10 Sin[π/3]}, {10 Cos[π/ 6], 10 Sin[π/3]}];
reg=RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2];  
 Area@reg
```

> $\frac{50 \pi }{3}$

```
Show[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 10]}, Axes -> True], 
 Region[reg, BaseStyle -> {LightBlue, EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}]}]]
```

[image]

You can also choose reg2 as

```
reg2 = Rectangle[{5, -5 Sqrt[3]}, {5 Sqrt[3], 5 Sqrt[3]}];
```

Or

```
reg2 = Rectangle[{5, -10}, {5 Sqrt[3], 10}];
```